# In langchain with ConversationalRetrievalChain, is it possible to use *only* local docuements and not general OpenAI data?

Tags: langchain

With langchain indexing local documents for OpenAI/ChatGPT with the ConversationalRetrievalChain, is it possible to query only local documents, and NOT include external data from OpenAI large language models?

This is possible with simple queries that do not use a chain. For example, this python code that gives users a choice of using external data *works*:

`if EXTERNAL_DATA: print(index.query(query, llm=ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo"))) else: print(index.query(query))`

However, when using a conversational chain, I haven't been able to leave out the llm.

This python code works, but will mix information from the local documents and the llm:

`chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm( llm=ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo"), retriever=index.vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 1}),`

The only documentation I've found for this is here: https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/agents/langchain.agents.agent_toolkits.conversational_retrieval.openai_functions.create_conversational_retrieval_agent.html

It refers to calling the llm, but offers no way to leave that out, and I get an error saying the llm is necessary if it's excluded.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behavior.
In fact, if you look at the source code, the second step of the chain promp is:

```
prompt_template = """Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end. If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer.

{context}

Question: {question}
Helpful Answer:"""
```

Answer (score 0):

**Not *really*.**

While you can engineer your own prompt or - as @Fran Casadome points out - rely on the instructions in the built-in Retrieval prompts, ultimately you are always merely *asking the model* to constrain it's answers.

Depending on how they were trained - and especially how they were fine-tuned with instructions as part of their training - different models will *obey* your instruction do different degrees. But, as far as I'm aware, there is none that will *guarantee* adherence to such an instruction.

It doesn't have to obey your instructions, and one day, it won't.

(And that's just for *"Limit your answer to these documents..."* instructions. Wait till you get to *"Open the pod bay door, Hal*" ;)

So if your use case is customer-facing, mission critical - don't depend on it. Go and google 'guardrails for LLMs'.